# Android: Initialize a socket only once durin app lifecycle

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth

I made an application that sends and receives data out of a bluetooth socket, everything is working fine for now, but it's only one activity so far, and I'm not sure how I'm supposed to keep the socket "alive" once I transition between activities.

What I'm doing now is in the `onCreate()` of the main activity, I am initializing a `socket` and a `thread` , so the communication doesn't make the UI freeze.What I'm not sure about is how am I supposed to keep those from being "destructed" or cleaned by the GC after transitioning to a new Activity, since they were instantiated in the main activity and should be gone after that is closed.

What I would usually do in a Java desktop app is instantiate a `static` or a singleton socket at the beginning of the `main()` block and that way it would be accessible throughout the whole application. But an Android application always start on some Activity.

How should I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Android Applications start from an Activity, there is the `Application` class in Android which you can extend and implement your code there. This will be accessible throughout the whole Application. See below code snippet.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // This will be called when the Application is starting
    }
}
```

You can instantiate a `static` or a singleton socket just like you do in Desktop Apps.

Checkout this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) for more info. Let me know if this helps !

Comment: From what I read in the link: I should subclass Application, initialize any global content in there, and then open other activities from that Application?

Comment: Yes, but what do you mean by open other activities from that Application?

Comment: After I'm done with initializing the socket and all ,I would want to start an actual Activity

Comment: You cannot start an Activity from Application class. The existing code whatever you have will stay the same, except you will be able to access the socket from anywhere using `MyApplication.getSocket();` once you instantiate.